# Помогите. Можно ли так составить предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Слёзы, в отражении которых переливалось пылающее солнце, закапали из глаз мальчика, сверкающими крупинками бриллиантов, которые стекая по грязной щеке превращались в черные капли.

Comment: Поэтично. Талант!)

Comment: Повторы неблагозвучны: "которых"/"которые, "закапали"/"капли". Одна запятая лишняя, а две необходимы.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  Александр, как из моей правки убрать повтор "закапали – каплями"?

Comment: @Sharon "...превращались в черные бусины". А можно заменить "закапали" на "потекли" (и тогда "стекая" на "сбегая" или "скатываясь") или "побежали" (что хуже). Надо думать, конечно...

Comment: Если потекли, то это уже не капли-бриллианты.

Comment: Ну да... "Пишите, Шура, пишите..."

Comment: На что вы намекаете?  Сами же поставили задачу – убрать повтор. Бусины тоже не подойдут.

Comment: Я только отметил то, что бросается в уши, а задачу убрать повтор поставили вы :) У меня это с наскоку не вышло. Вот и говорю, что надо думать.

Comment: Хотите сказать, что вы здесь не стояли? Ловкий ход,,  вам бы в адвокаты пойти...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Составить так можно. Но недостаёт пары запятых, а одна лишняя. Также определитесь, есть ли в вашем тексте ётирование, либо нет. Плюс опечатка в слове "крупинками". Правильно так: "Слëзы, в отражении которых переливалось пылающее солнце, закапали из глаз мальчика сверкающими крупинками бриллиантов, которые, стекая по грязной щеке, превращались в чёрные капли."

Answer (score 4):

Вариант редактирования:

*Слёзы, **в отражении которых переливалось пылающее солнце**, закапали из глаз мальчика крупинками бриллиантов – стекая по грязным щекам, они  превращались в черные капли.*

**Дополнение от 31.07.2022**

Вызывает сомнение выражение "слезы, в отражении которых..."

Вариант правки: *Слёзы, **в которых искрилось и переливалось пылающее солнце**, **покатились** из глаз мальчика крупинками бриллиантов – стекая по грязным щекам, они  превращались в черные капли.*

Comment: Вы говорите про сомнение... В таких случаях надо продолжать мысль, разобраться, почему вызывает. Это же самое интересное.